# Crysis 2 activation on Steam

Tags: pc, crysis-2

I'm thinking about picking up a copy of Crysis 2 on PC, and saw it for £8 in my local supermarket (a lot cheaper than on Origin) - I would love to use this on Steam instead, so can I activate the disk copy on my Steam account, or will I need to add this as a "non steam game" and therefore lose out on achievements, time played counter etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is no. The full list of accepted retail games is found [here](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7480-WUSF-3601) and a forum post, containing a similar question, is found [here](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1897822).